# Javascript loop array in realtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

is there a way to loop an array in "real time" in Javascript or using JQuery? What I mean is to create a loop that reads the array content without caching it before starting the loop, for example if I do this.

```js
var array = [{'hi':0},{'how':1},{'are':2},{'you':3}];

for(var i=0;i < array.length;i++){
  console.log(i);
  if(i == 2){
    array.push({'?':4});
  }
}
console.log(array);
```

The loop will output only 4 values but it already has 5 values before finishing the loop

I would like to also loop the new values inserted while the loop is running.

For more clarification, I need to do this because I am building a web app that creates a queue before submitting data to the server, a loop submits the data in the array but this array can also be updated in the process by other functions

Thanks!

Comment: It output 5 values. Your question is not clear.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal his question is clear to me - he wants to mutate the array during the loop, and wants the loop to keep going while insertions are made to the array

Comment: @duxfox-- yes, but he said that it was logging just 4 values, but it's not true, the loop is logging the entire array including the value added inside the loop, so 5 values

Comment: Are you forgetting that index starts at zero and 4 is actually the 5th iteration?

Comment: Add more logging details to your code and you will see the index you added at the end of the loop. `console.log(i, JSON.stringify(array[i]));`

Comment: @CalvinNunes oh I see, ok makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as you want. It works because at each iteration, you evaluate `i` against `array.length`, so even if the length changes during one iteration, the loop will adapt accordingly.

It would *not* work if you used :

```
for(var i=0, j=array.length; i<j; i++){
```

because in this case, the length is stored in `j`, and then `j` doesn't change, regardless of what happends in the loop.